# How to Attach Picture to Existing Email

Tags: ios, mail.app, email, iphone, attachments

How do you attach a picture to an email you've already started composing? Instead of going to the picture first and sending it that way. I want to be able to attach it **while** I'm writing an email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are using iPhone 4 from your tag.

1. Press Home button
2. Go to the Photos app
3. Long hold on the picture that you want to attach to the email. A 'Copy' pop up will appear, copy.
4. Go back to Mail.
5. Paste your photo into Mail.

Note that the photo will be in full size and might make the size of your outgoing mail quite large.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I'm just surprised that I can't "attach" easier while having the email still on the screen. Perhaps this is an oversight? Very cumbersome.

Comment: If there was a back button on the phone that would help, too.

Comment: This is the only supported method, Josh.

Answer (score 2):

While typing your email you can long click on any empty space. The Copy/Cut/Paste menu will pop up. There is a small right pointing triangle, if you press there you´ll see the option for inserting a picture or video.

Answer (score -1):

Yes I tapped the screen where I wanted the photo to go. And copy/paste comes up. Press copy and scroll along bar at the top of page until you get insert photo or video. Press that and choose from you camera roll. Paste and hey presto it's done. Actually I don't think you even need to do the C & P. Just press the screen and scroll along the top bar.